# How to copy Office 365 group membership to another group?

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm hoping there is a powershell command that can copy the group membership of an O365 group to a different O365 group. I got this from the web, but it's not working because my source group "is not a valid mailbox recipient."

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Source Group Name" |% {Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Destination Group Name" -Member $_.PrimarySmtpAddress}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be well known, but for those searching for this answer in the future, an Office 365 group is called a Unified Group in powershell. So I ended up figuring out how to do it with the below code:

```
$members = Get-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "Source O365 Group Name"
foreach ($item in $members) {
    Add-UnifiedGroupLinks -Identity "Destination O365 Group Name" -LinkType Members -Links $item.primarysmtpaddress
}
```

Thanks for your help in constructing the code Zack A!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Source Group Name"

Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Destination Group Name" -Member $members
```

if that doesn't work:

```
$members = Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Source Group Name"
foreach ($item in $members) {
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity "Destination Group Name" -member $item
}
```

All depends on if the -member parameter accepts an array or a single object. The documentation for the cmdlet is specific to exchange not OFfice 365 and could be a little dated. The documentation seems to indicate the -member parameter will not accept an array of objects so I suspect you'll have to use the 2nd approach.

Comment: The first line is giving me that same error "not a valid mailbox recipient".

Comment: The first line is the same in both code blocks. Maybe a "distribution group" is different than an "Office365 group"?

Comment: Well, it's working in my Office 365 environment. So it sounds like perhaps you're having an issue with the group name itself. Can you try that first line with a different group name - just to see if it works?

Comment: Probably because you are testing it out on an actual "Distribution List" type group, instead of an "Office 365" type group. See image here: [link](https://imgur.com/g0KVI2s) I may need to use the command "Get-UnifiedGroupLinks" to accomplish my task.

Comment: I'm sure that is what happened at my end. All our distribution groups are synced from on-prem. I'm glad you figured out the right cmdlet for the group type.